# Loading https via android webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to android and in my app, I need to get connection to an `https` for payment action and here's how my webview currently looks like when I try to make connection.

[image: webview fails]

I've looked up on the web for solutions to loading https via overriding `onReceivedSslError` method to ignore the error and proceed onwards. So, I have done so as the following.

Here's my webview getting its settings:

```
web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);

// setting WebViewClient
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.loadUrl(orderSheetUrl);
```

where `orderSheetUrl` is the https url to which my payment action takes the user to.

Below is my WebViewClient class:

```
private class WebViewClientClass extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("WebView", "in shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d("WebView", "onReceivedSslError");
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d("WebView", "onPageFinished " + url);
    }
}
```

The problem here is then I try to load the link, but find in my log that only the logs for `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` is being called.

Here's my logs:

```
12-13 17:06:31.760 8694-8694/? D/WebView: onPageStarted :"https://alpha-bill.payco.com/easyLogin/201512132004116802?inAppYn=Y"
12-13 17:06:31.760 8694-8694/? D/WebView: onPageFinished :"https://alpha-bill.payco.com/easyLogin/201512132004116802?inAppYn=Y"
12-13 17:06:31.790 8694-9927/? E/Adreno-ES20: <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
12-13 17:06:31.790 8694-9927/? E/Adreno-ES20: <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
12-13 17:06:31.800 8694-8694/? W/cr.BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 8694
12-13 17:06:31.810 8694-8694/? W/cr.BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 8694
12-13 17:06:32.180 8694-8795/? E/Adreno-ES20: <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
12-13 17:06:32.180 8694-8795/? E/Adreno-ES20: <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
```

I really don't get why the `onReceivedSslError` method is not called even when I access a url starting with https, which from my understanding should require a certificate to have an access.

Have I done something wrong with implementing my `WebViewClient`? Or is there any other way around this? Thanks in advance for the help.

P.S. my target API is 23 and minimum is 15.

Comment: check if the time is set properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Notify the host application that an SSL error occurred while loading a resource.

So why should it be called when there is no error?

Comment: I've edited my question. I forgot to mention that my webview fails to load and does not give ssl errors so I'm wondering what error that is.

Comment: could it be that you send the `"` characters as part of the URL?

Comment: Ahhhhh stupid me :( Thanks for the help! It was indeed passing url with the quotes!